# htaccess remove www from URL respect RewriteBase

Tags: .htaccess

In base directory it works fine, but if you go in subdirectory: example www.domain.com/dir/
 used RewriteBase is lost.
In htaccess  I have something like this....

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L]
```

So if we put www.domain.com/dir/home it redirect us to http://domain.com/home and /dir/ is missing ... 
What I is wrong ... Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put dir in Rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/dir/$1 [L,R=301]
```